# Spark streaming does not print some data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am analyzing Streaming Spark, and it works fine except printing out RMSE. So, it prints out the predictions `output.print()`, however it does not show RMSE. Any idea?

```
  def calculateRMSE(output: DStream[(Double, Double)], n: DStream[Long]): Double = {
    var summse = 0.0
    output.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.map {
          case pair: (Double, Double) =>
            val err = math.abs(pair._1 - pair._2)
            err*err
      }.foreach(summse += _)
    }
    math.sqrt(summse)
  }

//..
val trainingData = ssc.textFileStream("file:///home/gosper/Desktop/data/streaming/train").map(LabeledPoint.parse).cache()
val testData = ssc.textFileStream("file:///home/gosper/Desktop/data/streaming/test").map(LabeledPoint.parse)

model.trainOn(trainingData)
val output = model.predictOnValues(testData.map(lp => (lp.label, lp.features)))

output.print()

val rmse = calculateRMSE(output,testData.count())
println(s"RMSE = $rmse")

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would suggest to avoid updating outer `var summse` and use `.sum` (which is a reduce operation in map/reduce framework)

**UPD**
I was a bit wrong about the solution initially.
Here's one more idea. To print the value after the stream has ended.

```
var rmse : Double = 0
output.map {
  case pair: (Double, Double) ⇒
    val err = math.abs(pair._1 - pair._2)
    err*err
}.reduce(_ + _).map(math.sqrt).foreachRDD(rdd ⇒ rdd map { rmse = _ })

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()

println(s"RMSE = $rmse")
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but it looks like `summse` is `Unit` instead of `Double`:   `val summse = output.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.map {
          case pair: (Double, Double) =>
            val err = math.abs(pair._1 - pair._2)
            err*err
      }.sum()
    }
    math.sqrt(summse)`

Comment: consider using it more like this:
`val summse = output.map { case pair: (Double, Double) => val err = math.abs(pair._1 - pair._2); err*err } }.reduce(_ + _) 
val res = math.sqrt(summse)`

Comment: It says that `math.sqrt` expects `Double` instead of `DStream[Double]` that  is now the type of `summse`. Also, probably there should be `}.reduce` instead of `} }.reduce`.

Comment: Ok. I see. Since `DStream` is a stream of RDD's you'd need to make `}.reduce }.reduce` twice.

Comment: May I ask you put the whole example in your answer please. Thanks.